# How to create a Color Array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, colors

I want to create Color array for save some colors in it.

```
public static Color[] colors;

public void setColor()
{
    colors=new Color[3];
    colors[0]=R.color.disableColor;
}
```

here is color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="disableColor">#AAAAAA</color>
    <color name="activeColor">#D62D20</color>
</resources>
```

so its possible to do this ?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I would recommend storing them as constants

Comment: instead of posting here, you could try this.. that may take less time

Comment: You can try anything and if any errors or problem occur then can post here

Comment: yes I tried but not work simple i have to index does colors

Comment: @Enes Then  post proper question with error log and problem description

Comment: guys don't downvote without understanding the question properly. Sometime it happens that user may not be able to explain his/her requirement clearly. It does not mean to downvote and close even without try to understanding the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to create an array:

```
public static Color[] colors = new Color[] {
    R.color.firstColor, 
    R.color.secondColor
}
```